# How to slim down app.js in nodejs and koa2

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I have lots of codes in file `app.js`, and some of them like following

```
 const Router = require('koa-router')
 const router = new Router()
 router.get('/', async ( ctx )=>{ //lots of codes})
 router.get('/help', async ( ctx )=>{ //lots of codes})
 router.get('/signup', async ( ctx )=>{ //lots of codes})
 router.get('/signin', async ( ctx )=>{ //lots of codes})
 //and more codes
```

And now I want to slim down `app.js` from those routers, and I create a folder called `routers`, and I make each js file for each router, such as `help.js`, `signup.js`, `signin.js`, and how can I write those router files? and how can I use them in `app.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `help.js` could look like this:

```
'use strict';

exports.get = async (ctx, next) => {
    // your code goes here
}
exports.post = async (ctx, next) => {
    // your code goes here
}
```

In the `app.js` you then can do:

```
...

const help = require('./help'));

...

router
    .get('/help', help.get);
    .post('/help', help.post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your file's like this:

index.js ( Contain all the routes )
users.js, upload.js, stats.js etc..

Let's start from the users.js file
Here you can have multiple functions for example:

```
exports.getOne = async (ctx) => {
    // your custom code here
}

exports.getAll = async (ctx) => {
    // your custom code here
}
```

In your index.js

```
const Router = require('koa-router')
const router = new Router()
const users = require('./users')

router
   .get('/api/path/get', users.getOne)
   .get('/api/path/get', users.getAll)
```

Then in your app.js file you have:

```
const api = require('./api/index')

app.use(api.routes())
```